# wso2 api manager 1.6.0 query parameters not accepted

Tags: rest, wso2

I am using wso2 API manager 1.6.0 and would like to create an API which accepts any POST

on /users resource followed by any query parameter such as "clientid" (as described below)

restserver.com:8280/context/1/users?clientid=333

I have created an API in API publisher as follow :

URL Prefix       URL Pattern     HTTP Verb

/context/1       /users/*       POST

Any POST on /users is accepted but as sson as I add a query paramter /users?clientid=333 , the request is rejected by the API Manager gateway with 403 error.

Could someone advice me on this and what should be the correct url-mapping format ?

The resulting url-mapping in synapse config file is as follow : (synapse-configs/default/api/)

Thanks a lot.

JS

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to define `uri-template` instead of `uri-mapping`. [This blog post](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2012/10/url-template-url-mapping-and-their.html) explains more about this.

For your case I got it working as following.

- Open your API configuration source which can be found at `AM_HOME\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\api` folder.
- In the `resource` tag change `url-mapping="/users/*"` attribute to `uri-template="/users/*"`

But you will have to invoke the API as follows with additional context because when you say `/users/*` it means anything can come after `users/`. So you need to have a `/` after `users` context.

`restserver.com:8280/context/1/users/usr?clientid=333`